# How to develop/serve multiple pages using polymer starter kit

Tags: polymer, gulp, polymer-starter-kit

I have recently started working on polymer starter kit. I see that index.html is served as the site hosted at localhost:3000. It is a single page app, which handles a few routes client side. I am trying to build a multi page site using polymer. Pages would share some resources (toolbars, custom-elements) but are all single-page apps themselves.

Either I can:

1. Work and serve multiple pages on different routes from gulp server itself. Vulcanize can efficiently inline/pack the resources then.
2. Work on individual pages as separate projects. When deploying take their resources and merge manually.

Second option does not look like a good idea. How can I extend the starter kit to build/ serve multiple pages.

**Update**

I found that the starter kit uses browser-sync which handles routing but it is minimal. The workflow isn't working for me (anyone who knows better please suggest). You can build the frontend without routes, but when you have to take it to production you would want to integrate it with your server, which has routes. So integrating both and testing it end-to-end is complex and painful.

The lack of routing hurts me more than not having to reload my browser. By routing I mean mapping of URL's to files on disk. I would want to control it and change routes easily. I have decided to ditch browsersync and use the following workflow:

1. Gulp for frontend rebuild on file change
2. Express server for routing and serving the build reload on route change and above

Can anyone tell how to integrate both.

Comment: You can just add those extra pages inside the directory where `index.html` is located. Although you may have to edit any references of `index.html` inside your gulp file to include the other pages.

Comment: @NeilJohnRamal I added files there but there is no defined route to access them. index.html is also usually default route. If you know how to add routes please answer.

Comment: I think by default you can access them there. For example, I can type http://localhost:3000/home.html and it would render if it exists.

Comment: @NeilJohnRamal that is good but what if you want to test it with routes you want to use and without having .html at the end for them.

Comment: Doesn't the polymer starter kit provide a library (page.js) for client-side routing?

Comment: @NeilJohnRamal That works within the single app. But when you have multiple apps part of routing needs to be done at server side.